# What fundamental objects are missing in Object Oriented PHP?

Tags: php, oop, object

I've been coding with PHP for a while, and I've been relatively irritated at the inconsistencies in the procedural functions (especially Strings and Arrays).

With the support for objects, I've been wishing that PHP had a native implementation of Arrays and Strings as objects so that I could write code like:

```
$arr = new Array('foo', 'bar');
$item = $arr->pop();
```

Making an Array-like object isn't overly difficult, however, there's a significant performance hit. All it would end up being is a wrapper for the array constructs anyway.

Are there ***other*** core objects that PHP should have for Object Oriented PHP?

EDIT to add:

This is ***NOT*** about how you can use arrays as objects; in fact, I specifically do **not** want the discussion of arrays in the answer, as that's not what the question is about. I used arrays as an example, and it seems no one read the question. I am interested in **other** classes/objects that should exist natively in core PHP.

Comment: At least for the array example there are ArrayObject and SplStack. Maybe the coming SplString will add similar features and a method API for strings. But unless functions become first class objects, I see less use for having all basis types represented as objects. (PHP would have fared better by following Python rather than mimicking Java OOP features.)

Comment: Have a look at [SPL](http://php.net/SPL). Specificity, the `ArrayObject`.

Comment: I don't care about fundamental objects.  I would rather see support for converting objects to other fundamental types (such as ints, floats, booleans, etc).  Otherwise who cares if you have an SPLInt if you can't silently convert it as needed...

Comment: I don't understand why you need this. You can convert array to object by using (object) array(); but if you're concerned about performance than why don't you simply use array as array?

Comment: @SODA, it's not about *need*, it's all about **want**. @Tim Cooper, ArrayObject is missing most of the advanced array methods (diff, map, intersect, etc), so I consider it to be incomplete.

Comment: Well I am just curious, what reasons for wanting it do you have?

Comment: Consistency for object oriented design. The majority of my procedural calls are for arrays and strings, many of which don't follow a consistent pattern for naming/parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
It will be possible in PHP 6 with [aoutoboxing](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/autoboxing) 
is the automatic conversion the compiler makes between the primitive (basic) types and their corresponding object wrapper classes (eg, array and ArrayObject, double and Double, etc).
There would be a special function named __autobox()

```
    <?php
function __autobox($value) {
    return ... /* some object */
}
?>
```

For Example :

```
function __autobox($value) 
    {
        switch(gettype($value))
        {
            case 'integer':
                return new MyIntegerObject($value);
                break;

            case 'array':
                return new ArrayObject($value);
                break;

            default:
                $stdObj =  new stdClass();
                $stdObj->value = $value;
                return $stdObj;
                break;

        }
    }
```

**Example using:**

```
var_dump(5 == new MyInteger(5));
bool(true)
```

Comment: The question isn't about *how* to use arrays as an object, I already know about ArrayObject, ArrayAccess, Countable, IteratorAggregate, etc. Using any of those objects/interfaces only acts as a *wrapper* for arrays, rather than as a standalone object.

Comment: oh sorry, this will be possible in php 6.0  with [autoboxing](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/autoboxing)

Comment: Is PHP 6 here yet? Damn. * *crawls back into hibernation* *

Comment: Baris Yildirim, put the autoboxing stuff in your answer and I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could argue that PHP should convert or at least extend some of it's natives into an object equivalent and from an ease of use point of view you are right but SPL offers most of the things we need so nobody is really complaining. The way we work with arrays is flexible enough and doesn't consume unnecessary memory.

If I had to choose i'd rather have PHP streamline it's array api instead of just converting all arrays into objects. Why is it array_map and asort? Why not array_sort for example. It'd rather have them fix that in php6 and actually had the chance to ask Scott McVicar and Derick Rethans a few months ago and they responded that it would break backwards compatibility and anger the large userbase. Dumb answer but end of story i'm afraid.

But to answer your question, no ... i don't think PHP should adopt it's primitive types as language objects.

Comment: "It would break backwards compatibility and anger the large userbase" which is *exactly* why a native Array (or any other) object implementation can help *fix* the problem. The new object could be designed with consistency in mind, so that you're not constrained to inconsistent functions.

Comment: You don't need to convince me ... talk to the php core team :)